# Zero-width non-joiner allows unclickable titles

Tags: bug, status-completed, title, unicode

Using only a [zero-width non-joiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner), and maybe [other characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-printing_character), allows unclickable titles.

Now that Joel had to be the grown-up and spoil the fun, here's what the home page looked like:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I love the elegance of this bug report. So... self-referential.

Comment: I think it's hilarious that there isn't even anything to click on to get to this question from the Questions page.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't explain how to reproduce the bug. If I edit, the title is literally blank.

Comment: @gnovice the expert: That's why I edited the number in.

Comment: @Jon B: Actually, no, it's not.

Comment: If you normally browse the homepage instead of the Questions page, there's a usable link on there to get to the question.

Comment: @balpha - I'm looking at it in the edit page, and it's blank (using Chrome).

Comment: @Jon use 'View Source' and see the data inside of the value.

Comment: It is basically `|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||` @balpha could you explain why this works?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/comments-questions-and-answers-dont-trim-unicode-u200b-when-counting-characters

Comment: @NlfE: I guess Jeff forgot about titles. And probably tags, too.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: No, it doesn't work with tags. The character white list for tags is very restrictive.

Comment: @Joel - aw, spoilsport!  ;-P

Comment: @Joel: BOOOOOO!

Comment: I cannot enter the character, in windows, it gives me this: ♀

Comment: @Downvoter: Use the character map to choose & copy the character to the clipboard. That's what I did.

Comment: delete

Comment: I got it working on a title in a new question, but on comments it shows like my last one @bal

Comment: @Downvoter: That must be display issue on your side then; your comment is just blank to me.

Comment: Yay! I'm glad we got a screenshot of it. (Now my initial comment actually makes sense. lol)

Comment: @bal, It might be a chrome thing then... It shows a vertical bar (only one)

Comment: @Downvoter - I see one vertical bar in IE 7 as well - but no matter how carefully I position the mouse, the vertical bar is still unclickable!

Comment: @balpha: What is the slashed circle from?

Comment: @Gnome: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38738/greasemonkey-script-to-show-latest-activity-in-question-overview

Comment: Can someone put a blank comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214988/whats-the-best-strategy-for-team-room-music/313165#313165 ?

Comment: See comment on my answer below. We probably should not be allowing zero length spaces in comments, either. Regression? We used to check for that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How is this any different than posting a bunch of unicode spaces in the post body? Or other general abuse of the system?

The short answer is "don't do that", and the longer answer is "if you keep doing that, there will be consequences."

edit: I added the [zero-width non-joiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) to our length check routine. You'll have to move on to other more obscure unicodez.

Comment: That's an utterly boring answer. But since I tend to give the check mark to the official response, there you go.

Comment: @balpha you know what else is boring? Unicode spaces. *I'm just sayin*

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah. Why don't you two get a room, *you and ASCII*.

Comment: Unixode is not an abuse of the system. It merely shows that the system is underspecked.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ^ Methinks this is still broken, though how important that is, I don't know.

Comment: @wendi technically this is about Post TITLES, per the question.

Answer (score 18):

‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

Comment: How about user names?

Comment: I tried that once.

Comment: I have an account I use with a blank username that posts blank questions, blank answers, and blank comments. My posts are everywhere - and nowhere.

Comment: @Jon B: I feel like you're playing a game of Mad Libs with us. I pick the adjectives "smelly", "green", "wooden", and "effervescent".

Comment: @gnov - I do try to post effervescent comments...

Answer (score 2):

‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

In order to reproduce this, just use `&zwnj;` enough times to beat the minimum length filter. I even have it above this text.

You [can also type](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) `Alt+200B` in a text field.

Comment: But that shows it in the source

Comment: Yes. The character map method does as well.

Comment: let me try on my Linux workstation: fail.  Oh, no worries, I've got a Mac too, let me try again... fail.  Alt+200B.  Sure thing.