# Make 'zero width space' count as white space

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, whitespace

I don't know what [the reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4239412) were thinking, but this is not the issue here:

[image]

---

Rather, [the limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78159/whats-up-with-the-minimum-length-for-edits/78162#78162) was circumvented by inserting six [U+200B](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192) ([UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) E2 80 8B, "ZERO WIDTH SPACE") at the end of the sample code:

[image]

Should this be added to what is considered white space in the edit length restriction? Or does [the old policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119614/using-unicode-zero-width-spaces-allows-all-space-comments/119618#119618) still apply?

Comment: This​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: also​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: works​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: in​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: comments​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: !​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: One of the reviewers was the answerer BTW. Presumably the correction from 11 to 10 and additional colon was technically correct.

Comment: @MartinSmith It was reverted an hour later

Comment: @gunr2171 Oh yes. Strange!

Comment: I've seen many attempts to circumvent the six-character minimum, but this is a new one. (I'm also tempted to tear the editor a new one.)

Comment: It's one thing to use the zero width space in comments. But it's another to use it in edits to get around the 6-character minimum...

Comment: Alternate suggestion: Automatic moderator flag for suggested edits that are shorter than the length restriction after stripping out ZWSPs. :D:D:D

Comment: Unless there are many examples of abuse, there's little reason to act.  There are lots of ways to overcome the built in rules checker, but it's generally only necessary to strengthen rules when abuse is widespread and very detrimental. Otherwise you're going to spend significant development time making the rules checking huge and obese for very little return on your time investment.  Not only that, but the rules checker will run that much slower with each addition. You'll need to add many, many more examples of such abuse before it's worth acting on.

Comment: With Unicode being vast, there are *[many to choose from](http://www.bogofilter.org/pipermail/bogofilter/2003-March/001889.html)*, but if it is in some kind of table it might be feasible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the point of doing this? They'll just end up resorting to other, uglier ways to circumvent the limit.

Comment: Regarding the other issue: *[When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200336)*

Comment: Related: *[Null bytes accepted as part of text (not really)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145534)*

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any need for this.

Anyone using this kind of hack has probably evaluated trying to bring the edit up to 6 characters by more conventional means first and concluded that there aren't 6 such edits to be made.

I can't gauge the technical accuracy of this specific edit myself but, assuming that the missing colon was correctly added, it is difficult to see what other 5 changes they could have made to this 100% code answer.

The real purpose of this restriction is to ensure that editors fix everything in the post.

A much less exotic workaround they could also have used (apparently) [is simply adding `&nbsp;`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90014/145673).

Comment: The difference is that you actually _see_ `&nbsp;`, because it isn't zero-width. And there's no promise the user has tried to bring anything up to 6 characters: already knowing this trick, they could just say "I'll correct that, then insert a bunch of zero width spaces."