# Empty comments are allowed

Tags: bug, comments, mathjax

Whenever I try to put the comment `$ $$ $$ $$ $$ $` on a site that supports LaTeX, it results in an empty comment. And it succeeds! Try it for yourself (I don't encourage spamming, delete the comment afterwards). **[Mathematics.SE](//math.stackexchange.com)** and **[Puzzling.SE](//puzzling.stackexchange.com)** are examples. **Codegolf.SE** is not an example, as it doesn't support LaTeX.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240175/thousands-of-itty-bitty-comments-that-break-the-15-character-minimum-rule http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245131/theres-a-loophole-for-the-15-characters-per-comment-requirement

Comment: @random That one was closed as duplicate (second) :( I want empty comments to END! If the comment length is <15 chars, `$`s should be shown and no expressions will be evaluated. NOW, WHAT?

Comment: Now we calm down because there is no need to flip out

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I apologise, was just verifying the postulate.

Comment: @ABcDexter Apologise? You don't have any reason to apologise, I understand you. You can safely delete your comment now.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really an issue and I guess these comments are rapidly flagged on active sites. Moreover, there are tons of way to produce white space with Mathjax such as `\phantom{blabla}`, `\quad`, `\qquad`, `\ \ ` , `\color{white}{blabla}`, combinations of these, etc...

Comment: @Surb I mean, really empty comments, not just whitespace.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος You want empty comments? Simply add a lot of negative spaces with `\!` to get rid of the white space or simply write any white expression followed by a nice little `\hspace{-500cm}` to make sure your white space disappear.

Comment: @Surb I think the comment I describe in the question (`$ $$ $$ $$ $$ $`) does not have any spaces, because MathJax suppresses them. It's also the simplest I've ever crafted.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Have you tried the comments I suggested?... [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/avHR2.png)'s a screen shot with `$ $$ $$ $$ $$ $` above and `$\!\!\!\!\!\! $` below. There is definitely no difference. Anyway I hope that is not your main point... Because if you want to avoid empty comment, avoiding just one type of them makes little sense to me (either all or none).

Comment: @Surb I said something about the difference of "visually empty" and "really empty" comments.