# Arabic diacritic unicode characters break title links

Tags: bug, status-declined, title, unicode

[Arabic diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_diacritics) are passing the filter, giving the ability to write almost an empty title or an empty body of a post. I think it has to be filtered before submitting.

When writing Arabic and using them, they are supposed to be used with letters (on َtَoَp or ِbِoِtِtِoِm), they can never be used alone anyway. Still, when adding them alone in the title and *then add some in the body*, they pass the filter. When only added in the title, they will not pass the filter

Not sure if the same happens with diacritics from other languages as well.

One thing to notice, these characters are not clickable in the questions page.ََََََََِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِّّّ⁭⁭⁮⁮⁭⁭⁮⁮⁭⁭⁭⁭ ََََََََِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِّّّ

Comment: Lol, I can't even click it :D

Comment: Very much related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44011/zero-width-non-joiner-allows-unclickable-titles

Comment: @nicael Ask another question, asking why some question can not be clicked :D

Comment: App users have no problems. Ha.

Comment: @SimonKlaver As an Android app user, I got here without difficulty

Comment: For iOS app users, an underline of sorts shows before the apostrophe thingy in the question list and the title bar, however in the question itself it does not show.

Comment: I got here by clicking on the number of "votes"

Comment: I had no trouble clicking the title, but that turns out to be because of [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup), which [makes the entire title block clickable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287222/clicking-between-lines-fails).

Comment: [Well, if we fix this, then this answer wouldn't be so fun.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5299236)

Comment: @Kevin why? It's not like SO will block all unicode. Maybe just in title, but surely not in posts.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Huh, however OP said that *or an empty body of a post*.

Comment: @Kevin Zalgo will be furious if you claim he's empty. ;) ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: Thank you v. much for fuzzing the UI. You are doing a great job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yup, you found something that is definitely annoying but it's not worth it to fix it.

In the [words of Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44113/164200):

> The short answer is "don't do that", and the longer answer is "if you keep doing that, there will be consequences."

I'll just reiterate what he said with this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the title should be "Arabic character cause empty titles", it's not only about breaking the link. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Considering it's empty it breaks the link :P

Comment: oooh, the same does not apply to the body anyway ;)

Answer (score 12):

Apparently, the link has a special character that cannot be chosen. What I mean by that is that if you try to highlight or delete this special letter, it will simply not disappear. To me, this means that this is a valid character but would not be able to be linked by the system.

The special character:
[image]

Seemingly, SOUP has already has this fixed so a quick transfer from there to the actual system should render these characters fixable.

> I had no trouble clicking the title, but that turns out to be because of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup), which [makes the entire title block clickable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287222/clicking-between-lines-fails). - Ilmari Karonen

The link seems to think that the letter of this question's title is:

> %D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%91%D9%91%D9%91%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E

It would make sense that you would not be able to link something to that string of characters. What I think the system feels about unicode titles:

[image]

Clearly the unicorn's name is Evil Unicode not Twinicode hence ***uni*** corn and ***uni*** code instead of ***twin*** icode.

Comment: Placing your marker at the end of the url and pressing backspace 32 times removes it.